# java list of object visible through all app

Tags: java, variables, interface

I have an Object named Person(name, surname, age)
This Object is populated with values from a local file.
But i want to keep this object visible through the app since there is a GUI for adding new values to this.
I was trying to put an Interface like this but doesn't work

```
 public interface MyInterface{

    public List<Person> myPersonObj = new ArrayList<Person>();

}
```

and to call it in app like `MyInterface.myPersonObj` 
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's in an interface it will automatically be `final` (read-only), thus you probably want to put it in a class instead:

```
public class AnyClass{
  public static List<Person> myPersonObj = new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

Then you can do:

```
AnyClass.myPersonObj
```

to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the variable static, e.g.

```
public static (final) List<Person> persons = new ArrayList();
```

For more information, read about the [Singelton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

make the list **static** inside the class where you populate it.

```
class Populate{
    public static List<Person> myPersonObj;
    public static void setMyPersonObj(List<Person> inst){
         myPersonObj =inst;
     } 
    public static List<Person> getMyPersonObj(){
        if(MyPersonObj!=null){
          return myPersonObj;
       }
       else {
         return new ArrayList<Person>();
       }
    } 
   //populate it 
}

class SomeOther {
public static void someMethod(){
  Populate.getMyPersonObj();
}
```

}